# React Lazy Not working for Production Build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

In my current project, I am using lazy for my routes. It's working perfectly on local but for the production build, it's giving me multiple issues.

When I try to redirect on one of the lazy routes it tries to access the chunk for the relative path and not the base path. something like below

https://myapp.com/mypath/static/js/1.2324dfg.js

instead of https://myapp.com/static/js/1.2324dfg.js

I am preparing the production build simply with **npm run build** prod command. Please let me know if I am missing any setting.

Comment: did you check for applying a Suspense component over your lazy loaded components?

Comment: @humanbean  Yeah I did and it's working perfectly on local. Its just issue with the prod path.Not sure what should be set so that it will access resources from base path and not relative path

Answer (score 5):

Can you try putting this line in your package.json file? I had the same issue and now working fine with this setting. Good luck

```
"homepage": "/",
```